# C++ - How to make a class constructor from arithmetical-type array with const size?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, sfinae

I have class `Q` and want to make a constructor from arithmetical-type array with size of 3. I've tried to use templates, `std::enable_if` and `std::is_arithmetic` and have got the following code:

```
class Q {
public:
    template <typename T> 
    Q (typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type (&v)[3]) {
        first = v[0];
        second = v[1];
        third = v[2];
    }
private:
    double first, second, third;
}
```

But this code:

```
int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
Q q(arr);
```

Doesn't compile, because there is no constructor for such types of argument: int[3]. Are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: It is unclear what things are supposedly named "first", "second", "third" and "fouth"[SIC]. What it means doesn't work and what is the problem?

Comment: "But it doesn't work on this code:" *How* does it not work? Does it not compile? Please copy and paste any error you get from th compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something as follows ?

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct Q
 {
   template <typename T, 
             typename = typename std::enable_if<
                                    std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
    Q (T const (&v)[3])
     { /* do someting */ }
 };

int main()
 {
   int arr[3] {1, 2, 3};

   Q a {arr}; // compile
   Q b {{1, 2, 3}}; //compile
   //Q c {{std::string{"1"}, std::string{"2"}, std::string{"3"}}}; // compilation error
 }
```

The problem with your original code is that with

```
template <typename T> 
Q (typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type (&v)[3])
```

the compiler can't deduce the type `T` (if I'm not wrong is because the type of `v` is of the type `type` that is after `::` that is no deducible context).

So you have to permit the `T` type deduction (I suggest to add `const` so the constructor can accept also right-values so can accept also `Q b {{1, 2, 3}};`)

```
template <typename T>
Q (T const (&v)[3])
```

and, if you want SFINAE enable/disable the constructor, you can work over an additional template parameter as in my preceding example.

Comment: Thanks, your code is a solution. But I've got a new question: when I try to declare constructor in Q.hpp and initialize it in Q.cpp, I have an error like this: "unable to determine the default template argument in the class template member declaration outside the corresponding class".

Comment: @Yaroslav - I don't know exactly what your problem (what do you mean with "declare constructor in Q.hpp" and "initialize" (?) "it in Q.cpp"?) but I give you a suggestion: never place template elements (functions, classes, method, variables) in cpp files; only in headers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your class `Q` should be a template over type of its `first`... members.

Let's assume this is undesirable for some reasons and you really want to keep it concrete with e.g. `first`... of large enough type, e.g. `int64_t` (be aware of possible issues with signed/unsigned mismatch). In this case you can rely on compiler to check assignment:

```
struct Q {
    template <typename T> 
    Q (T v[4]) {
        first = v[0];
        // ...
    }

    int64_t first;
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    int arithmetic[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    int* not_arithmetic[4] = {};
    Q q_a{arithmetic};
    // Q q_na{not_arithmetic}; // error: assigning to 'int64_t' from incompatible type 'int *'
}
```

The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: In your code there is an opportunity to call the constructor from arrays with size more or less than 4, and it is problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

After declare

```
int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Q q(arr);
```

you have type int[4] v&[4] but you need only int.
For this you can declare whole class as template.

```
template <typename T> class Q {
 public:
       Q (typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type (&v)[4]) {
         first = v[0];
         second = v[1];
         third = v[2];
         fouth = v[3];
     }
 };
```

and use it as

```
int arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Q<int> q(arr);
```